# Undefined index: view with external url menu

Tags: php, joomla-3.3.x, menu

I am using Joomla 3.3.1 with SEO links on, and after changing a menu type to external menu (which points to a PDF), I am getting the following PHP notice:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: view in
>   /mysite/components/com_content/router.php on line 70

I went to the rounter.php and can see the following at line 70:

```
if (($menuItem instanceof stdClass) && $menuItem->query['view'] == $query['view'] && isset($query['id']) && $menuItem->query['id'] == (int) $query['id'])
```

Well, this is really a matter of having a `if (isset($query['view']))` but I don't want to edit the core file.

Also there will be a problem with `isset($query['id'])`, that's because the URL in the menu is an external URL wich will not have an ID nor a view.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had this issue myself. The problem was that the client had internal links that were not relative and were linking to the proper page but with these weird URLs.

Once the internal links on the page were resolved (relinked properly), the error that you've posted disappeared.

Good luck!

Comment: It was some internal (outdated) links in the template that pointed to the old menu. After updating those the error went away. Thanks!